# Circuit equivalence for cotrolled-controlled-$R_y$ gate

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-circuit

Could someone explain the following equivalence to me?
[image]

I can build an example for the case when the first two lines of qubits are equal to 1. However, what happens if they are both equal to 00, 01 or 10? And what is the role of $R_y(-\theta)$?

Comment: I am also studying this. Can you tell me the source of the circuit?

Comment: This circuit is what is being used for FRQI encoding in Quantum Image Processing. You can find more here: https://github.com/Qiskit/textbook/blob/main/notebooks/ch-applications/image-processing-frqi-neqr.ipynb

Also almost every paper that talks about FRQI has this scheme for reference if you want to know more about the subject.

Comment: "QUANTUM COMPUTING_ From Linear Algebra to - Mikio Nakahara" It would be nice to see related formulas on page 104 of this book. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call the first two qubits used for control $q_1$ and $q_2$. Let the for them be denoted as $|q_1q_2\rangle\,.$

For the left-hand side circuit, you know that for

$$\begin{align} 
|q_1q_2\rangle &= |00\rangle\,,\\
|q_1q_2\rangle &= |01\rangle\,,\\
|q_1q_2\rangle &= |10\rangle\,,
\end{align}$$
the action should be nothing, and for $|q_1q_2\rangle = |11\rangle\,,$ $R_y(2\theta)$ gate should be executed on the third qubit.

Now, let's consider the right-hand side circuit.

#### - Case 1: $|q_1q_2\rangle = |00\rangle$

Here, none of the controls are activated, $\text{CNOT}$s also do nothing and hence whole circuit does nothing.

#### - Case 2: $|q_1q_2\rangle = |01\rangle$

Control for first $R_y(\theta)$ is $0$. It does nothing. Control for first $\text{CNOT}$ is also $0$. It does nothing. Control for $R_y(-\theta)$ is $1$ and hence $R_y(-\theta)$ is performed on the first qubit. The second $\text{CNOT}$ also does nothing. The control for the last $R_y(\theta)$ is $1$, and hence $R_y(\theta)$ is performed on the third qubit.

Hence, the total operation is

$$
\begin{align}
U &= R_y(\theta)\cdot R_y(-\theta)\,,\\
&= I\,.
\end{align}
$$

You can explicitly prove the above equations by taking a [matrix representation of the $R_y$ gate](https://www.quantum-inspire.com/kbase/ry-gate/). However, intuitively, you can think that you are first doing a rotation along $Y$-axis by $\theta$ in an anti-clockwise direction (the operation $R_y(-\theta)$) followed by a clockwise rotation along $Y$-axis by $\theta$ (the operation $R_y(\theta)$) and hence, in total, you don't do any action. You are back to where you started.

#### - Case 3: $|q_1q_2\rangle = |10\rangle$

The control for first $R_y(\theta)$ is $1$. You perform $R_y(\theta)$ on the third qubit. The first $\text{CNOT}$ makes the second qubit 1. Now, the control for $R_y(-\theta)$ is $1$. You perform $R_y(-\theta)$ on qubit 3. The second $\text{CNOT}$ makes the second qubit $0$ again. Now, for the last $R_y(\theta)$, the control qubit is $0$, and hence you do nothing.

Hence, the total operation is

$$
\begin{align}
U &= R_y(-\theta)\cdot R_y(\theta)\,,\\
&= I\,.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you!